# Fazer com que combinador de classes abra a página em aba separada

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Galera tenho um código no qual ele me cria uma página como se fosse um tema, pegando aleatoriamente as classes css, porém o que ele faz é criar o "tema" dentro da página que esta o botão, e gostaria que ele abri-se uma nova página com o tema selecionado.

Segue o código js

**Código que gera as classes**

```
var classesRM = ['fundoRomantico', 'fundoRomantico1', 'fundoRomantico2'];
var classestopoRmt = ['topo-romantico', 'topo-romantico1', 'topo-romantico2'];
var classesmenuRmt = ['romantico-menu-01', 'romantico-menu-02', 'romantico-menu-03'];
var classesfootRmt = ['footer-romantico', 'footer-romantico1', 'footer-romantico2'];

var classesFontTexto = ['font-romantico', 'font-romantico1', 'font-classica', 'font-classica1', 'font-moderno', 'font-moderno1'];
var classesFontTitulo = ['font-titulo-romantico', 'font-titulo-romantico1', 'font-titulo-classica', 'font-titulo-classica1', 'font-titulo-moderno', 'font-titulo-moderno1'];
var classesMenu = ['menu-01', 'menu-02', 'menu-03'];
var classesTexto = ['textoBranco', 'textoPreto', 'textoCinza'];
function sorteia(arr) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr[rand];
}
```

**Código do botão**

```
document.getElementById('troca').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var classeRM = sorteia(classesRM);
    var classetopoRmt= sorteia(classestopoRmt);
    var classemenuRmt= sorteia(classesmenuRmt);
    var classeFontTexto = sorteia(classesFontTexto);
    var classeFontTitulo = sorteia(classesFontTitulo);
    var classeTexto = sorteia(classesTexto);
    var classeMenu = sorteia(classesMenu);
    var elemento = document.getElementById('navbar');
    elemento.className = classemenuRmt;
    var elemento = document.getElementById('nav-bar');
    elemento.className = classeMenu;
    var elemento = document.getElementById('titulo');
    elemento.className = classeFontTitulo;
    var elemento = document.getElementById('topo');
    elemento.className = classetopoRmt;
    var elemento = document.getElementById('body');
    elemento.className = classeRM + ' ' + classeTexto + ' ' + classeFontTexto;
});
```

Comment: Queres que abra uma nova página ou na mesma página?

Comment: quero que abra em nova pagina, tipo os botões ficarem em uma tela e quando clicar o tema gerado seja aberto em uma pagina diferente sem os botões

Comment: Ok, e o conteúdo dessa página é o mesmo que a primeira?

Comment: Sim sim, pq esse é para ser o modelo, então eu conseguindo fazer com que abra em nova pagina, ja começo para ver o conteudo

Answer (score 1):

Se mudares a tua lógica um pouco consegues fazer como queres.

Usa o event handler só para abrir uma nova página:

```
document.getElementById('troca').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var win = window.open(location.origin, '_blank');
  win.focus();
});
```

e depois dentro de cada página correr o resto do código no load da página:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var classeRM = sorteia(classesRM);
    var classetopoRmt= sorteia(classestopoRmt);
    // etc...
```

O código completo poderia ser:

```
(function () {
    var classesRM = ['fundoRomantico', 'fundoRomantico1', 'fundoRomantico2'];
    var classestopoRmt = ['topo-romantico', 'topo-romantico1', 'topo-romantico2'];
    var classesmenuRmt = ['romantico-menu-01', 'romantico-menu-02', 'romantico-menu-03'];
    var classesfootRmt = ['footer-romantico', 'footer-romantico1', 'footer-romantico2'];

    var classesFontTexto = ['font-romantico', 'font-romantico1', 'font-classica', 'font-classica1', 'font-moderno', 'font-moderno1'];
    var classesFontTitulo = ['font-titulo-romantico', 'font-titulo-romantico1', 'font-titulo-classica', 'font-titulo-classica1', 'font-titulo-moderno', 'font-titulo-moderno1'];
    var classesMenu = ['menu-01', 'menu-02', 'menu-03'];
    var classesTexto = ['textoBranco', 'textoPreto', 'textoCinza'];

    function sorteia(arr) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        return arr[rand];
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('troca').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var win = window.open(location.origin, '_blank');
            win.focus();
        });

        var classeRM = sorteia(classesRM);
        var classetopoRmt = sorteia(classestopoRmt);
        var classemenuRmt = sorteia(classesmenuRmt);
        var classeFontTexto = sorteia(classesFontTexto);
        var classeFontTitulo = sorteia(classesFontTitulo);
        var classeTexto = sorteia(classesTexto);
        var classeMenu = sorteia(classesMenu);
        var elemento = document.getElementById('navbar');
        elemento.className = classemenuRmt;
        var elemento = document.getElementById('nav-bar');
        elemento.className = classeMenu;
        var elemento = document.getElementById('titulo');
        elemento.className = classeFontTitulo;
        var elemento = document.getElementById('topo');
        elemento.className = classetopoRmt;
        var elemento = document.getElementById('body');
        elemento.className = classeRM + ' ' + classeTexto + ' ' + classeFontTexto;
    }
})();
```

Seria interessante optimizar esse código para não ser tão extensivo. Ou seja fazer o mesmo mas com menos linhas de código. Não mexi nisso, fica para outra pergunta.

Comment: O código window.onload eu coloco ele aonde?

Comment: @VictorSaul editei a resposta. Assim podes colocar em qualquer lado dentro do HTML.

Comment: Desculpa mas esse código não funcionou, ele abre direto ja a tela com o tema e quando clica no botão para fazer o embaralhamento ele abre a tela porém sem conteudo

Comment: @VictorSaul tens isso online? ou podes recriar o problema num jsFiddle com o teu código para eu poder ajudar mais?

Comment: Tenho no jsFiddle um exemplo do meu código, claro que no meu local ele esta mais elaborado com imagens em bg e tal mas a estrutura dele é essa https://jsfiddle.net/jpcaja7t/18/

Comment: @VictorSaul acho que devia ter usado `.pathname`. É assim que queres? -> http://jsfiddle.net/p2rmre5z/1/show/

Comment: Isso, porém não quero que apareça os botões na tela que foi gerada, quero que os botões fiquem em uma tela e ao clicar ele gere o tema sem os botões

Comment: @VictorSaul outra coisa... esse código está a dar-me dores de ver... posso mudar o HTML? Manter isso vai ser impossivel...

Comment: @VictorSaul perdi algum tempo a fazer isto -> http://jsfiddle.net/jafxrpkv/ Acho que o código devia estar assim. Já não tenho tempo de olhar para o resto. Mas no fundo podes passar no url o estilo numa query string e o JS ir ver se há algo para ler e esconder ou não os botões. Amanhä dou uma olhada aqui de novo.

Comment: OK, eu só preciso mesmo que consiga abrir o tema que me der em uma nova aba sem aparecer os botões